# How to handle translations for many languages with many different contexts?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Forever i have been doing my translations in the same table where object/element is created.
So for example if i work with posts and title of post needs a translation i do this -> `post_title_en`, `post_title_fr`, `post_title_nl`.
Well, this is quite terrible way to maintain application, you have to hard code in a lot of stuff in your code.

So i'm writing an application at the moment and i would like to break out of this bad habit to translate like this.

How would i approach translations if i don't know what kind of data length i have to hold in table fields?

I could have translation for `post_title` witch typically would be `varchar(255)` and i could have something like `post_content` witch typically would be `text`. And how would i reference all this with main object?

Any pointers are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL database is schematic. But you can do the trick.

Starting with version 5.0.3, if the [ROW_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-row-format.html) for table is set to "COMPACT", NULL values will never use any space in your database. So we could build the scheme like

[image: i18n scheme]

Answer (score 0):

Create another table consisting something like this:

- post_id (foreign ke to id field of posts table)
- field_type (title, content, etc.)
- language_id (the language)
- value (the string value)

so don't put any language affected values in the posts table (you can still put post author, date and time, etc).